# Runing npm run deploy:twilio-cli causes the following error

Tags: twilio

C:\Users*****\Documents\Sparo\twilio-video-app-react> npm run deploy:twilio-cli

> twilio-video-app-react@0.1.0 deploy:twilio-cli C:\Users*****\Documents\Sparo\twilio-video-app-react
>   cross-env REACT_APP_SET_AUTH=passcode npm run build && twilio rtc:apps:video:deploy --authentication=passcode --app-directory ./build

'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! twilio-video-app-react@0.1.0 deploy:twilio-cli: `cross-env REACT_APP_SET_AUTH=passcode npm run build && twilio rtc:apps:video:deploy --authentication=passcode --app-directory ./build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the twilio-video-app-react@0.1.0 deploy:twilio-cli script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users*****\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-04-14T16_44_28_493Z-debug.log

Comment: Did you run `npm install` before you ran `npm run deploy:twilio-cli`?

Comment: Yes. I ran npm install before npm run deploy.

Comment: That's odd. I can see that [`cross-env` is part of the package.json](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-react/blob/7f4f33c70e3f4424bbb74b989cb025d13d473a01/package.json#L20) in the latest version. Perhaps try `npm install cross-env` and try again?